# How can I install XMBC on top of the "recommended" Raspbian image?

Tags: kodi

Per [RaspberryPi.org](http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads), "Raspbian Wheezy" is currently the recommended image for your Raspberry PI.  What is the best path for installing XMBC on top of this distro of Linux? `sudo apt-get install xmbc` does not yield results. Should I compile from source? If I do, will I have the GPU hardware support?  Is there a modified version of XMBC that I should compile from?  Is there an available binary?

*FYI, I'm aware of [Raspbmc](http://www.raspbmc.com/), but my goal is to do this installation on top of the canonical "Raspbian" distro.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

XBMC isn't in the raspbian repos, but [someone does maintain a binary package](http://michael.gorven.za.net/raspberrypi/xbmc) for it.

I'm not sure what you mean by installing "on top of".  It's just an application, so this is much like saying, "I'd like to install firefox *on top of* raspbian".  What's it going to be on top of?

Comment: Forgive my prepositions.  Some would think of applications as being a layer on top of the OS.  I do not want to reflash my Raspberry Pi.

Comment: @RossRogers To get picky ;) the architecture of the system is in layers, yes, so you might refer to "the application layer" as synonymous with userspace, or as part of userspace, or in reference to a specific software stack.  You might also say something is "on top of" something in such stack, eg, firefox runs *on top of* Xorg.  However, "raspbian" refers to the system as a whole, so you are actually installing xbmc *into* raspbian, not on top of it.  You might say "into the raspbian userspace" which is *on top of* the linux OS kernel, but just plain "installing" will do.